# How can I make a flat window resizable?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Background:**

Hello. I'm currently trying to make a custom flat style window in Windows Forms for a school project. The idea is to use this window as a base and create other windows that inherit from it. The style I'm trying to achieve is similar to that of Visual Studio 2017 itself (Dark theme). I'm trying to add functionality to the window, like:

- Double clicking on the top panel maximizes the window (Done).
- Dragging the window wit the top panel (Done).
- Color changing border when focus/unfocus (Done).

The problem comes when trying to make the window resizable by dragging the borders.

**What I have:**

Here's an image of the [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8rqL.png).

The form has 2 panels:

- The top panel: It as a window icon, a label for the name of the window, and 3 buttons (minimize, maximize, and close).
- Main panel: It is an empty panel, this is where the content of the window will be.

The form has a 1px padding (the color changing border, this will come up later)

**The problem:**

I found this answer that seemed to solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32261547/70345 but when I try to implement it doesn't work entirely. What people seem to do is draw rectangles around the form and detect in the WndProc function if the cursor hovers over them:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) // you can safely omit this method if you want
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, Top);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, Left);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, Right);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, Bottom);
}

private const int
    HTLEFT = 10,
    HTRIGHT = 11,
    HTTOP = 12,
    HTTOPLEFT = 13,
    HTTOPRIGHT = 14,
    HTBOTTOM = 15,
    HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16,
    HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;

const int _ = 10; // you can rename this variable if you like

Rectangle Top { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, _); } }
Rectangle Left { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, _, this.ClientSize.Height); } }
Rectangle Bottom { get { return new Rectangle(0, this.ClientSize.Height - _, this.ClientSize.Width, _); } }
Rectangle Right { get { return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - _, 0, _, this.ClientSize.Height); } }

Rectangle TopLeft { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, _, _); } }
Rectangle TopRight { get { return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - _, 0, _, _); } }
Rectangle BottomLeft { get { return new Rectangle(0, this.ClientSize.Height - _, _, _); } }
Rectangle BottomRight { get { return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - _, this.ClientSize.Height - _, _, _); } }


protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    base.WndProc(ref message);

    if (message.Msg == 0x84) // WM_NCHITTEST
    {
        var cursor = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

        if (TopLeft.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT;
   else if (TopRight.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT;
   else if (BottomLeft.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT;
   else if (BottomRight.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT;

   else if (Top.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOP;
   else if (Left.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTLEFT;
   else if (Right.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTRIGHT;
   else if (Bottom.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM;
    }
}}
```

But when I do that, the rectangles are drawn behind the panels, so even if I set the rectangle's size (the "_" variable) to 10px or 20px, the area where I can click to resize the window is always 1px (because of the form padding).

I also tried using some sort of overlay and draw the rectanges there: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26071/Draw-Over-WinForms-Controls

But I had the same problem.

**What I need:**

I need to somehow draw the rectangles in front of the panels so I can have a bigger area to resize the form. I'm not very experienced in programming so I'm open to any sugestions and improvements. Alternate solutions are also welcome.

This is my form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BaseWindow
{
    public partial class BaseWindowForm : Form
    {
        public BaseWindowForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region draggable window
        private bool windowDragging = false;
        private Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);

        private void TopPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            windowDragging = true;  // _dragging is your variable flag
            startPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }

        private void TopPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            windowDragging = false;
        }

        private void TopPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (windowDragging)
            {
                Point p = PointToScreen(e.Location);
                Location = new Point(p.X - this.startPoint.X, p.Y - this.startPoint.Y);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region border color focus
        private void BaseWindowForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204);
        }

        private void BaseWindowForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(63, 63, 70);
        }
        #endregion

        #region maximize/minimize
        private void BaseWindowForm_Maximize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            }
            else if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
        }

        private void ButtonMinimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
        #endregion

        private const int
            HTLEFT = 10,
            HTRIGHT = 11,
            HTTOP = 12,
            HTTOPLEFT = 13,
            HTTOPRIGHT = 14,
            HTBOTTOM = 15,
            HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16,
            HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;

        const int _ = 10; // you can rename this variable if you like

        Rectangle Top { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, _); } }
        Rectangle Left { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, _, this.ClientSize.Height); } }
        Rectangle Bottom { get { return new Rectangle(0, this.ClientSize.Height - _, this.ClientSize.Width, _); } }
        Rectangle Right { get { return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - _, 0, _, this.ClientSize.Height); } }

        Rectangle TopLeft { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, _, _); } }
        Rectangle TopRight { get { return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - _, 0, _, _); } }
        Rectangle BottomLeft { get { return new Rectangle(0, this.ClientSize.Height - _, _, _); } }
        Rectangle BottomRight { get { return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - _, this.ClientSize.Height - _, _, _); } }


        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref message);

            if (message.Msg == 0x84) // WM_NCHITTEST
            {
                var cursor = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

                if (TopLeft.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT;
                else if (TopRight.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT;
                else if (BottomLeft.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                else if (BottomRight.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT;

                else if (Top.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOP;
                else if (Left.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTLEFT;
                else if (Right.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTRIGHT;
                else if (Bottom.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more details you can download the source code here: https://github.com/RndmDud/FormBaseWindow

Answer (score 2):

you can increase form padding (set it to ex: 2,2,2,2) 
Please check :([Can't resize a borderless winform from top because of a docked panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443474/cant-resize-a-borderless-winform-from-top-because-of-a-docked-panel))

Edit:

as in the same link as @Outman suggested to change the boarder color:

```
        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);            //comment this out to prevent default painting 
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(45, 45, 48))) //any color you like  }
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.ClipRectangle);
        }
    }
```